# Html.BeginForm() не передает модель

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

Есть типизированная `View`

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.EditVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h3>Редактирование графика работы по элементу содержания</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CountHours, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })         
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CountHours, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2">                
                <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-success" />        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Также в контроллере есть метод для `POST`-запроса:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditVM model)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Succes!");
    return View(model);
}
```

Но после нажатия на `Сохранить` приложение не попадает в этот POST-запрос, а выводит:

> Ошибка сервера в приложении '/'.
>
> Для данного объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов.
>
> Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего
>   веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных
>   сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.
>
> Сведения об исключении: System.MissingMethodException: Для данного
>   объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов.

Для интереса ради я создал в контроллере тот же пост-метод **без параметров**:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Validation succes!");
    return View();
}
```

Так действительно!!! Приложение обрабатывает именно этот метод). Ничего не пойму.

Как мне получить заполненную модель из View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В сообщении об ошибке

> Для данного объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов.

скорее всего имеется ввиду класс `WebApplication1.Models.EditVM` - в нем должен быть конструктор без параметров. У вас в нем (наверное) есть только конструтор, требующий параметров, и model binder падает при попытке создать объект `EditVM` из пришедших данных.